# Java ImageIO exception

Tags: java, embedded-resource, javax.imageio

Whilst running a code to display a pacman level background, I run into the problem of the image and pacman sprite not loading.

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1388)
    at org.pacman.Pacman.init(Pacman.java:51)
    at org.game.engine.GameLoop.run(GameLoop.java:26)
```

Line 26 of GameLoop is simply `game.init();`.

And here is the class:

```
public class Pacman extends Game {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GameApplication.start(new Pacman());
    }

    private BufferedImage sheet;
    private int frame;

    public Pacman() {
        title = "Pacman";
        width = 176;
        height = 258;
        frame = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        if (sheet != null) {
            g.drawImage(sheet, -2, 0, null);
            //draw ms pacman
            g.drawImage(sheet.getSubimage(628+(frame/3)*(15+2), 33, 15, 15), 80, 105, null);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void init() {
        try {
            sheet = ImageIO.read(Pacman.class.getResource("/images/pacman.png"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Pacman.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void update() {
        frame++;
        if (frame > 3*2) {
            frame = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your path to `pacman.png` correct or do you need to drop the leading `/` ?

Comment: in the source folder I have an images folder, and a pacman folder, images contains the image, and pacman contains the code

Comment: Have you checked the Jar to ensure the image is in the path you expect it to be?

Comment: It's all in the right directory in the jar

Comment: 1) It is at `"/images/pacman.png"` as opposed to `"/images/PacMan.png"`? A Jar entry is case sensitive. 2) Add @PersonName to notify the person of a new comment.

Answer (score 3):

> at org.pacman.Pacman.init(Pacman.java:51)

So look at line 51:

```
sheet = ImageIO.read(Pacman.class.getResource("/images/pacman.png"));
```

So `Pacman.class.getResource("/images/pacman.png")` is `null`, so it looks like it's not loading the image.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I noticed too, i changed the location and tried there, i also tried naming the image pacman.png(was actually pacman.png.png). but still no luck

Comment: @user1766588 According to your comment on the question, the image is in the source folder. My guess is that it's not on the classpath. You probably need to make your build process copy the images folder to the class output folder.

Comment: that works fine, the pathway is correct too as the images folder is in the source

Answer (score 2):

Try invoking `ImageIO.read` with `getResourceAsStream`, but check that `InputStream` for `null` beforehand. You'll find that it is indeed `null`. That means that the image cannot be retrieved at that URI.

Comment: getResourceAsStream didn't change anything, I'm aware it can't find my image, but I don't know how to get it to recognize it. Loading images in java is my bane.